# Book about a girl who finds out she was a fairy sent away to keep her safe, and gets sent someone to protect her

Tags: story-identification, books, fairy

I’m pretty sure the cover has the girl in a dress sitting down next to a pool of water. She was born a fairy but brought up as human and eventually finds out she was actually a fairy sent away for her own protection. She gets sent someone to protect her and basically, in the end, she falls for him and he says *"I don’t love you"* or something like that and disappears.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Please take a look at the prompts in [this thread](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question), and then [edit] your question to add any further details you may recall. The more info you can give us, the better the chances that someone will be able to ID this for you. In particular, it'd be helpful to know in roughly which year you read this, and when you think it might've been published.

Comment: very superficially trueblood - where there any other details about what being a fairy meant, what the powers were, who was chasing her?

Comment: I also thought of *Trueblood* - or *The Southern Vampire Mysteries*. as the books are called. However, I believe the vampires would be the thing to remember.

Comment: Sounds similar to Fate: The Winx Saga on Netflix.

Comment: I think her parents were really important in the car world and they were going to get attacked by their enemies or something like that so they sent her away

Comment: This is ringing all kinds of bells for me ... but I just can't think of the book :(